# SOAPUI - Assert error thrown even condition is true

Tags: soapui, assert

I'm getting assert error even though the condition is true as shown below:-

[image]

Anything missing here?

Comment: The screenshot it's okay, however the next time please add the code as text this way it's easy to play with, and if it's not a problem add it to this question as well `:)`

Comment: It is preferrable to convert both of them into integers and compare.  `assert Integer.parseInt(jdbcCount) == Integer.parseInt(dataSourceCount)`

Comment: @Ramu `dataSourceCount` is already and `Integer` and [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) is not applicable for integers. However your approach for this case is also valid but only applying to `jdbcCount`: `assert Integer.parseInt(jdbcCount) == dataSourceCount`.

Comment: @albciff  - Yes next time i will put code also..thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are that object types are different.

`jdbcCount` internally is a `String` however `dataSourceCount` is an `Integer`. This is why you see in the log the same value however assert fails.

Try using `toString()` to convert `dataSourceCount` to `String` and to pass the `assert` correctly:

`assert jdbcCount == dataSourceCount.toString()`

Or alternatively as @Ramu suggest on the comment due the values are numbers rather than compare strings, compare integers passing  `jdbcCount` to `int`:

`assert Integer.parseInt(jdbcCount) == dataSourceCount`

Hope this helps,